# Having issues attempting to hide content using .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to build a template builder of sorts for a client and was hoping for some advice on how to hide a template block once it's been brought into the builder. The basic idea is you have a simple page that holds a list of HTML template blocks that the user can select to build their template - assuming here that #content is the container that holds the separate template blocks.

I'm bringing in content from an external HTML file using this:

```
$('.add-section').click(function() {
    var content = '';
    $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
        url: "sections/new-section.html",   
        async: false,
        success : function(text)
        {
            content = text;
        } 
    });
$( '#content' ).append( content );
return false;
});
```

This works fine, however I'd like to include a "hide" button inside the HTML blocks so once inside the builder the user has the option to hide it if it's repeated or not necessary.

I've attempted to use .hide() below but to no effect.

```
$(".hide").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent('table').hide();
return false;
});
```

Any help would be greatly received!

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: I've set up a fiddle to show how it may look: http://jsfiddle.net/abbas_arezoo/r33L5/2/

Comment: Probably `$(this).parent().parent('table')` does not point to correct element. Try to use `$(this).closest('table')` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since the items are loaded dynamically

```
$("#content").on('click', '.hide', function () {
    $(this).closest('table').hide();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', '.hide', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r33L5/3/

Comment: Hey - I've tried this and it almost works how I'd like. I do want the ability to include several of the same sections and be able to hide them one-by-one. Your solution hides them all and then doesn't allow me to put the sections back in - if you follow?

Comment: Updated fiddle - I'd like to remove one by one your solution removes them all: http://jsfiddle.net/abbas_arezoo/r33L5/2/